# Delete map from subcollection Firestore/Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm doing an Android project with Firestore database in it.
I'm having trouble trying to delete a subcollection map at it, can anyone help?

Image of the subcollection

[image: Image of the subcollection]

I want to delete this whole red block. This is my method:

```
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection("roteiros").document(collectionId)
                .collection("eventos").document(subcollectionId)
                .delete()
                .addOnSuccessListener(successListener)
                .addOnCompleteListener(completeListener)
                .addOnFailureListener(failureListener);
```

This method is returning with success, but don't actually delete the doc.

I've already allowed all permissions in the database rules and tested on the simulator with the document path.

Comment: What you're highlighting isn't a subcollection.  It's an array field.  You'll have to write code to read the document, modify the array in memory, and update the eventos field with the new contents of that array.

Comment: Isn't "eventos" a subcollection? I want to delete it's documents, as "0" highlighted above. I'll try that.

Comment: It's not a subcollection.  As I said, it's an array type field.  0 is the index of the array.  Subcollections appear in a different box than the document fields, and you have to click into it to see the documents inside.

Comment: Oh! Good to know! I'm getting started with it, thank you for the support! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the FieldValue.delete()

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("roteiros").document(collectionId)
    .collection("eventos").document(subcollectionId)
    .update("eventos", FieldValue.delete());
```

NOTE: You cant delete a specific index in an array. you can only delete the whole array and recreate it with another set of data.

Comment: But I want to delete the entire map (document '0'). With _update_ I'll have to delete field by field, and not the whole map, right?

Comment: You have a misunderstanding between arrays and fields in Firestore.
A field is a data (arrays, string, timestamp, int).
within arrays are called indexes which starts with 0, 1, 2..... until how many data you added.

Using update with FieldValue.delete() with a field you can only delete the whole array and if you have the existing data, recreate the array with the modified indexes in it.

Comment: it would be much better if you dont use an array. Instead make it as a field inside your Document if you want it to update the data.